# How to save an Image from a PictureBox to my database?

Tags: vb.net, input, insert, save

```
private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System. Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If conn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
        conn.Close()
    End If
    If Trim(txtcode.Text) = "" Then
        MsgBox("Please enter the unique Member code")
        txtcode.Focus()
        Exit Sub
    ElseIf IsNumeric(txtName_Surname.Text) Then
        MsgBox("Please replace numbers with text", MessageBoxIcon.Stop)
        txtName_Surname.Focus()
        Exit Sub
    Else
        Try
            Dim strinsert As String
            Dim cmdinsert As OleDb.OleDbCommand
            Dim Passport As String = Application.ExecutablePath
            strinsert = "insert into book_mast (Mem_code,Name_Surname,Date_of_Birth,Gender,Telephone_number,Age,Status,Date_of_Baptism,House_No,Occupation,Education,Office_Name,Tel,Office_No,Tithe_per_month,Total_tithe_per_year,Born_Again,BA_Time,Baptizism,Baptizism_where,Join_RCCG,Join_Where,Baptizism_Ghost,BPG_When,Tongues,Tongues_When, Passport) values(@txtcode, @txtName_Surname, @d1, @txtgen, @txtTelephone_number, @txtage, @CbBStatus, @d2, @txthno, @TxtOccupation, @CbBEducation, @TxtOffName, @TxtTel, @txtOno, @txtTithe_per_month, @txtTotal_tithe_per_year, @TxtBornAgain, @TxtBornwhen, @CbBbaptizism, @TxtBaptizedwhere, @TxtJoinRCCG, @TxtJoinWhere, @TxtHolyGhost, @TxtGhostWhen, @TxtTongues, @TxtTonguesWhen, @Passport)"
            cmdinsert = New OleDb.OleDbCommand(strinsert, conn)
            conn.Open()
            cmdinsert.ExecuteNonQuery()
            MsgBox("Record Has been added Successfully")
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        Finally
            conn.Close()
            clearall()
            fillgridmem()
        End Try
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly is the question so I can help and try edit the question and wrap the vb code in "{}" and if the code is giving any errors.

Comment: Please reformat so it's more human-readable

Comment: I don't see where you are assigning values to your parameters.

Comment: I don't see any effort to save an `Image` there so what's the actual problem? If you search the web for how to save an `Image` to a database then you'll find plenty of information so there's no reason that you can't make an attempt at least.

Comment: Apart from that, a title that is a question and a question that is nothing but code is unacceptable. Please take the site tour (the one you were prompted to take but refused) and spend some time in the Help Center to learn how to write a proper question.

Comment: Don't; save it to a disk filesystem and put the filepath in the database instead

Comment: You haven’t given any info on your DB system.  Have a look at the varbinary equivalent data type for your dB management system.

Comment: Please, all I want is to add a passport photo to my database for every data I save. I already added the PictureBox and included it in my access database, but how to include it in my code is the challenge. The error message says "No value given for one or more required parameters".  Kindly help me @SMHasnain, Technonaut, Johnpete22

Answer (score 0):

I have created a small program to help you understand. In this case i have created a database in access but you can use the database you have.

[image]

```
Dim cnString As String = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Persist Security Info=False;Data Source=..\Data.mdb"

Dim imgName As String
Dim daImage As OleDbDataAdapter
Dim dsImage As DataSet

Private Sub FillCombo()
    Try
        Dim CN As New OleDbConnection(cnString)

        CN.Open()
        daImage = New OleDbDataAdapter()
        daImage.SelectCommand = New OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM images", CN)
        dsImage = New DataSet("dsImage")

        daImage.Fill(dsImage)

        Dim dtable As DataTable

        dtable = dsImage.Tables(0)
        cboImageID.Items.Clear()

        For Each drow As DataRow In dtable.Rows
            cboImageID.Items.Add(drow(0).ToString())
            cboImageID.SelectedIndex = 0
        Next
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub btnLoad_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnLoad.Click
    Try
        Dim dlgImage As FileDialog = New OpenFileDialog()

        dlgImage.Filter = "Image File (*.jpg;*.bmp;*.gif)|*.jpg;*.bmp;*.gif"

        If dlgImage.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
            imgName = dlgImage.FileName

            Dim newimg As New Bitmap(imgName)

            imgSave.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage
            imgSave.Image = DirectCast(newimg, Image)
        End If

        dlgImage = Nothing
    Catch ae As System.ArgumentException
        imgName = " "

        MessageBox.Show(ae.Message.ToString())
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString())
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Try
        If imgName <> "" Then
            Dim fs As FileStream

            fs = New FileStream(imgName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)

            Dim picByte As Byte() = New Byte(fs.Length - 1) {}

            fs.Read(picByte, 0, System.Convert.ToInt32(fs.Length))

            fs.Close()

            Dim CN As New OleDbConnection(cnString)

            CN.Open()

            Dim strSQL As String

            strSQL = "INSERT INTO Images([Image]) values (" & " @Img)"

            Dim imgParam As New OleDbParameter()

            imgParam.OleDbType = OleDbType.Binary
            imgParam.ParameterName = "Img"
            imgParam.Value = picByte

            Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand(strSQL, CN)

            cmd.Parameters.Add(imgParam)
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

            MessageBox.Show("Image successfully saved.")

            cmd.Dispose()
            CN.Close()
            CN.Dispose()
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try

    FillCombo()
End Sub

Private Sub btnRetrieve_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnRetrieve.Click
    Dim dataTable As DataTable = dsImage.Tables(0)

    If imgRetrieve.Image IsNot Nothing Then

        imgRetrieve.Image.Dispose()
    End If

    Dim fsImage As New FileStream("image.jpg", FileMode.Create)

    For Each dataRow As DataRow In dataTable.Rows
        If dataRow(0).ToString() = cboImageID.SelectedItem.ToString() Then

            Dim blob As Byte() = DirectCast(dataRow(1), Byte())

            fsImage.Write(blob, 0, blob.Length)
            fsImage.Close()
            fsImage = Nothing

            imgRetrieve.Image = Image.FromFile("image.jpg")
            imgRetrieve.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage
            imgRetrieve.Refresh()
        End If
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub frmMain_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    FillCombo()
End Sub
```

If this does not solve your problem or give any errors let me know I will look into it.

Comment: I have this code but how to personalize it is my challenge, can I share my code with you?

Comment: Sure do share your code so i can make changes.